# Prevent child overflowing parent when both are inside scrollable container

Tags: html, css

Consider the following code snippet:

```css
.scrollable {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.parent {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.child {
  background-color: red;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

When scrolling the horizontal scrollbar to the right, you can see that the `child` element (red) overflows the `parent` element (blue). It is also noticed that the parent takes the width of the `scrollable` container. What CSS styles are required for the parent element to horizontally grow with the child, as it does vertically, inside of the scrollable area?

Answer (score 0):

The only style property that is missing to have the parent element horizontally grow with the child is `display: inline-block` on the `parent` element:

```css
.scrollable {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
}

.parent {
  display: inline-block;
  
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.child {
  background-color: red;
  width: 400px;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<div class="scrollable">
  <div class="parent">
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```